# Using a Modal inside a list seems to pick the last value of the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a list of cities and I'm trying to include a modal with a trash can icon to delete the city next to each item. The problem I have is that the modal seems to pick the last item of the list for EVERY item on the list.
When you click on the icon on any element on the list the confirmation modal always points to the last element on the list and I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. :(

I tried using a Confirm element instead only to find out it's using the modal underneath and I get the same results.

Any gurus around who can help me troubleshoot this will be greatly appreciated!

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { List, Icon, Modal, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

const CitiesList = () => {
  const [deleteButtonOpen, setDeleteButtonOpen] = useState(false);
  const cities = [{ name: "London" }, { name: "Paris" }, { name: "Porto" }];
  const handleConfirmDeleteCityModal = useCallback(city => {
    console.log("[handleConfirmDeleteCityModal] city", city);
    // dispatch(deleteCity(city))
    setDeleteButtonOpen(false);
  }, []);

  const showDeleteCityModal = useCallback(() => {
    setDeleteButtonOpen(true);
  }, []);

  const handleCancelDeleteCityModal = useCallback(() => {
    setDeleteButtonOpen(false);
  }, []);
  return (
    <List>
      {cities.map(c => (
        <List.Item>
          <List.Content className="list-item-content">
            <List.Header as="h4">{c.name}</List.Header>
          </List.Content>
          <List.Content floated="left">
            <Modal
              size="tiny"
              open={deleteButtonOpen}
              onClose={() => handleCancelDeleteCityModal()}
              trigger={
                <Icon
                  name="trash alternate outline"
                  size="small"
                  onClick={() => showDeleteCityModal()}
                />
              }
            >
              <Modal.Header>{`Delete City ${c.name}`}</Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Content>
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this city?</p>
              </Modal.Content>
              <Modal.Actions>
                <Button negative>No</Button>
                <Button
                  positive
                  icon="checkmark"
                  labelPosition="right"
                  content="Yes"
                  onClick={() => handleConfirmDeleteCityModal(c)}
                />
              </Modal.Actions>
            </Modal>
          </List.Content>
        </List.Item>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};

export default CitiesList;
```

Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-borg-56bwg?from-embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
             <Modal
              size="tiny"
              open={deleteButtonOpen}
              onClose={() => handleCancelDeleteCityModal()}
              trigger={
                <Icon
                  name="trash alternate outline"
                  size="small"
                  onClick={() => showDeleteCityModal()}
                />
              }
            >
```

you use single flag `deleteButtonOpen` for controlling visibility of all modals. When you set it to true I suppose all modals are opened and you see only the latest one.

Normally I would render single modal and pass as props content of which item I want to show inside.

But if not using separate `open` flag for each modal should fix it, e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-banzai-byc4t

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm such a newbie with JS and React!! That makes total sense!! 

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If it is not too much to ask... how do you render a single modal and pass content as props in this scenario? It sounds like a more elegant solution :)

Comment: this should give you a rough idea: http://codesandbox.io/s/musing-elgamal-upf3f